# CoffeeScript Class Variable undefined 1.9

Tags: variables, constructor, coffeescript, undefined

So I am looking at CoffeeScript code that is not mine, I am trying to understand why a class variable is undefined. The CoffeeScript Runtime is 1.9

```
class CommandParser

obj:
   message: null
  indicator: 'warning'
  stackTrace: null
  result: null
  isException: false

constructor: (@command, @params, @result) ->
@obj.result = result //@obj is undefined
```

I am trying to understand why @obj is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your indentation really looks like:

```
class CommandParser
  obj:
    message: null
    indicator: 'warning'
    stackTrace: null
    result: null
    isException: false
  constructor: (@command, @params, @result) ->
    @obj.result = result
```

then you're not getting a TypeError for `@obj` being `undefined`, you're getting a ReferenceError because there is no `result` variable.

When you say:

```
m: (@i) -> ...
```

for any method then the `@i` in the argument list automatically assigns that parameter value to the `@i` instance variable on your object but there won't be an `i` local variable. So your `constructor`:

```
constructor: (@command, @params, @result) ->
```

automatically sets the `@command`, `@params`, and `@result` instance variables when you call it but there is no `result` local variable anywhere in sight. If you want to look at the `result` value then you'd look at `@result`:

```
constructor: (@command, @params, @result) ->
  @obj.result = @result
  # ------------^
```

or you'd leave the `@` off in the argument list:

```
constructor: (@command, @params, result) ->
  @obj.result = result
```

That's the obvious bug taken care of, the hidden bug comes next. When you define something at the class level:

```
class C
  p: { a: 11 }
```

then `p` is part of `C`'s prototype so it is shared by all instances of `C`. In your case, there is only one `@obj` object that will be shared by all instances of `CommandParser` so if you say:

```
c1 = new CommandParser('c1', 'p1', 'r1')
c2 = new CommandParser('c2', 'p2', 'r2')
```

then both `c1.obj.result` and `c2.obj.result` will be `'r2'` because they're both using exactly the same `@obj` reference.

> Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kffswpxm/

Defining mutable values at the class level is almost always a mistake, define them in your constructor so that each instance gets their own:

```
class CommandParser
  constructor: (@command, @params, @result) ->
    @obj =
      message: null
      indicator: 'warning'
      stackTrace: null
      result: @result
      isException: false
```

> Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/k3kmg1cc/

If you want to define them at the class level for documentation purposes then you'd want to clone it in your constructor:

```
class CommandParser
  obj:
    message: null
    indicator: 'warning'
    stackTrace: null
    result: null
    isException: false
  constructor: (@command, @params, @result) ->
    @obj = _(@obj).cloneDeep()
    @obj.result = @result
```

> Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/r69vood7/

That example uses [`cloneDeep` from Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep), there are similar cloning tools in just about every utility belt JavaScript library.